# Meteor React component onClick event not working in IE

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am currently developing a small Meteor application using React and have run into an issue(seemingly overnight, perhaps caused by an update?) where my onClick events are not firing in IE, but work fine in other browsers.

Please see the following example -

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function ()
    {
        React.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
    });
}


TestComponent = React.createClass({

    showAlert()
    {
        alert("On click!");
    },

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div><button onClick={this.showAlert}>Click Me</button></div>
          )
    }
});
```

The code simply loads a button on the page and shows an alert when clicked. This works fine in Chrome/Firefox, but the alert is not shown in Internet Explorer. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

It appears there have been some issues with the latest version of React. Looks like a fix will be shipped tomorrow:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5324